# How to select columns with subset of another column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have a complicated version of this problem ([How to select columns with same set of values in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653271/how-to-select-columns-with-same-set-of-values-in-mysql)) to deal with.

In a relation R(A,B,C), The problem is to figure out  **"A's with 4 or more common B's"**. FYI: "AB" is a candidate key.

All I was able to do is this

**Query:**

```
select * from 
(select A, group_concat (B separator ', ') all_b's from R group by A having
(count(B))>3) p1  
join  
(select A, group_concat (B separator ', ') all_b's from R group by A having
(count(B))>3) p2  
on p1.all_b's = p2.all_b's and p1.A <> p2.A;
```

**Output:**

```
Null Set
```

But, the answer is supposed to be something else. 
Any idea how to deal with this?

**Sample Data:**

```
A   B   C
a1  b1  asdas  
a1  b2  sdvsd    
a1  b3  sdfs  
a1  b4  evevr  
a2  b1  jdjd  
a2  b2  dkjlfnv  
a2  b3  sdfs  
a2  b4  evevr  
a2  b5  adfgaf  
a3  b1  sdfsdf
```

**Expected Output**

```
A   A  count
a1  a2  4
```

Comment: What is the output you expect from the sample data you provide? Please update your question with this information.

Comment: You want all results in a sigle line (1 registry) ?

Comment: No. I would like to see a pairs of A's in each line that have 4 or more common B's.

Comment: Would that be ok? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ada2cd/6 let me know, I will add as an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't correct. We are supposed to compare B's of A's. The A's we compare should be distinct. In the link you provided, you joined using 'A', that's right ! But, it doesn't compare the B's of A's. Please check the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like that:

```
SELECT
    first.A AS first_A,
    second.A AS second_A,
    COUNT(*) AS countSameBs
FROM
    R first
JOIN
    R second ON
    first.B = second.B AND
    first.A != second.A
GROUP BY
    first_A, second_A
HAVING
    countSameBs >= 4 AND
    first_A < second_A
```

Comment: @VarunKumarChepuri Try append `AND first_A < second_A` to the `HAVING` clause as seen in my edited answer.

Comment: It is pretty much right but the output i get for this is

    Output:   
    
    A B C  
    a1 a2 4      
    a2 a1 4

Comment: Thanks a lot! You appended the less than condition in the having clause only because the list of A's where in increasing order, i suppose. What if the list was not sorted? Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: @VarunKumarChepuri: The sorting/order doesn't matter, it just ensures that you get the combination of (a1, a2) only once and not the symmetric combination (a2, a1) as well.